# CSS same height blocks

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ktmzk3jk/

I'd like to make the red background on the blocks the same height.

I'm sure I could do it with Jquery but is there a standard CSS soultion.

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4 col"> 
                <div class="block">
                    <h3>65%</h3>
                    <p>Some Text Some Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4  col"> 
                <div class="block">
                    <h3>20%</h3>
                    <p>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4  col"> 
                <div class="block">
                    <h3>5%</h3>
                    <p>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: How about adding a `height` to `col-sm-4`? [See](http://jsfiddle.net/ktmzk3jk/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ktmzk3jk/6/)**

**CSS:**

```
.row-full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.col-full-height {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row-same-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /* fix overflow */
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.col-xs-height {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-same-height row-full-height">

      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-height col-full-height">...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't style  that inner `<div class="block">` , in fact you shouldn't even have it there;

directly style the `.col` selector,

[here you have  a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ktmzk3jk/5/).

Comment: If I style the col directly I lose the margin between the blocks. I thought it's best to keep the structure and styling separate.

Comment: adding another selector to divide bootstrap structure from your style is a good idea but you can just add that selector to the div with class .col without creating an inner div

Answer (score 0):

For equal size red blocks, you need to update value of height in `.block`, set height to `height:150px` instead of `height:100%` if you know the maximum height. Otherwise also include `overflow:auto;` so that a scroll appears if text goes beyond the boundary
Updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktmzk3jk/8/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `min-height` to would be the best approach but I would recommend a jQuery approach. Especially if the content changes to different lengths often.